# Why does the main document extend sprite in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

What is the purpose/benefits of this extending sprite:

> public class Main extends Sprite

Comment: It can extend any kind of `DisplayObjectContainer`. It must do it because it must be able to add children in it. There are no benefits of Sprite before MovieClip.

Comment: Ok thanks so basically you cannot add children unless the main class extends sprite/movieclip etc.

Comment: It won't let you compile if it doesn't extend it.

Comment: The document class, in Flash, must extend MovieClip because the main timeline is a MovieClip.

Comment: @Craig That is false. It must extend `DisplayObjectContainer`, which `MovieClip` also extends. Most Actionscript based applications do not actually use the timeline (in fact, it is recommended that they do not)

Comment: @JoshJanusch Touché. But what if I want my document class to add dynamically created objects or, otherwise, to behave like a MovieClip?

Comment: @Craig Then you use `MovieClip`. All I said was that it doesn't **have to** extend `MovieClip`. Regardless, the overhead required for `MovieClip` over `Sprite` is not small. As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid using `MovieClip` whenever possible, especially on mobile.

Comment: You need top extend MovieClip only with a Flash IDE project that has at least 2 frames in its timeline. If you have only one frame or for any other project types you only need Sprite.

Answer (score 2):

The document class is added automatically as a child of the Stage when your app starts. In consequence it needs to be a DisplayObject. It also need to be a DisplayObjectContainer so that DisplayObject can be added to its display list.